# Laravel 5 just show index page on xampp server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, xampp

I'm running a Laravel 5 project as `test.dev` (vhost) on XAMPP, in my `routes.php` just have 2 routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('hello', function () {
    return "Hello Laravel 5!";
});
```

When I visit `test.dev/`, it shows Laravel welcome page, but when I visit `test.dev/hello` it can't find the route and redirect to Google. There's no errors on Apache `error.log`. What is the problem? Is something I need config on XAMPP?

Vhost configuration on XAMPP is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/test/public/"
       ServerName test.dev
       <Directory   "C:/test/public/">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The welcome page has by default his own controller. Did you made also a controller for your  'hello' page?

Comment: @Franco: it should work like he wrote. There is an anonymous function that handles the logic ;)

Comment: It just return a string "Hello Laravel 5!", it doesn't need a controller.

Comment: @Justin: sounds like a mod-rewrite problem. Also, I would recommend to use homestead or an other vm

Comment: Oh Yeah! I had not seen that he is just returning a string

Comment: @Justin test.dev/index.php/hello solves the problem?

Comment: I checked httpd.conf, it is "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so", no comment at this line, something else in XAMPP?

Comment: @ssi-anik,  test.dev/index.php/hello doesn't work :)

Comment: what about php artisan server? localhost:8000/hello ?

Comment: If I run php artisan serve instead of XAMPP, it works well, I can visit both routes.

Comment: can you edit the question? and add vhost ?

Comment: @ssi-anik, vhost config has added.

Comment: @Justin, can you remove the extra slashes from the end? not sure about that.

Comment: @ssi-anik, removed and restarted Apache in XAMPP, same problem.

Comment: @Justin, can you try this? move to another folder. For me on windows, it worked. Not sure about folder permission. http://paste.ubuntu.com/14091360/

Comment: @ssi-anik, I tried same things in the folder where I installed XAMPP, doesn't work, anyway, thanks so much "ssi-anik". I'll leave a while.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the problem, Change

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride all
```

then it works well.